# Azure AD authentication fail after inactivity

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We are developing an .net core Azure Web App and for authentication we use cookie authentication and open id connect authentication.

When going to the start page of our application everything work's as it's supposed to. But leaving page inactive for around 10 minutes and then clicking on any of the links in the page we get following exception:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.microsoftonline.com/f505412d-3150-4f15-a704-b6ce122de04d/oaut…mdOd12SMYufhag1Ysv-9E2WHXJHApMyfCDDaVtKQ4pcaiB7PyUpieC2a51_AvlB4f5KL7oN21C. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:54538' is therefore not allowed access.
```

But when refreshing everything work's as it's supposed again. Has anyone seen this problem and found a solution for it?

Our Startup-file contains following code in method Configure:

```
app.UseSession();
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
  AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
  AutomaticChallenge = true,
  LoginPath = new PathString("/Authentication/Login")
});
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
  ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"],
  Authority = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"] + Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:TenantId"],
  PostLogoutRedirectUri = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:PostLogoutRedirectUri"]
});
```

And in method ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
services.AddSession(options =>
{
  options.CookieName = "cBook.Session";
  options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
});
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
  options.Filters.Add(new ExceptionFilter());
  options.Filters.Add(new ActiveDirectoryAuthorizationFilter());
  options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(
    new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
      .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
      .Build()
  ));
});
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions => sharedOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddSingleton(_ => Configuration);
```

I would appreciate all help I can get.

Thanks,
jan.

Comment: Is your frontend built with a JS framework?

Comment: Yes, it's an .Net Core application with an Angular front.

Comment: The 10 minutes is pretty weird, but my theory of what is happening is: Angular makes an AJAX request to get something when you hit a link. The server decides it's unauthenticated and sends back a redirect to Azure AD. The AJAX request tries to hit Azure AD and fails because it does not support CORS.

Comment: If my theory is correct, you have two problems. Why is the request unauthenticated after only 10 minutes? And you must handle the unauthorized situation a bit differently. I would also suggest you to look into the Implicit Grant Flow, as that is designed specifically with JS front-ends in mind. You would then change your backend to use JWT authentication instead of Open Id Connect.

Comment: At this moment it's not possible for me to change to another framework. I know it's possible to get this working since we're using same technology in other applications. The code only differs in details but I can't seam to find the reason behind this problem.

Comment: I have now found a solution, but I still don't really understand how this all works. If a set the property UseTokenLifeTime then the application site can be inactive for 1 hour before I get the same error.
    
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
    {
        ClientId = Configuration[...],
        Authority = Configuration[...] + Configuration[...],
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = Configuration[...],
        UseTokenLifetime = true
    });

Comment: `UseTokenLifetime` sets the authentication cookie to expire at the same time as the token that it gets. The default expiry time for them is one hour.